Unable to call system (malloc, printf) from c module when loaded by python
The following code works, but when I add the commented statement (new int) it fails with:
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libkv_module_shared.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
C++:
int a = 7;
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) size_t setup() {
    //new int; works unless commented in
    return ++a;
}
}

Python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import os
import ctypes

#DLL_REL_PATH = './cmake-build-debug/'
DLL = 'libkv_module_shared.dll'
DLL_FULL_PATH = "C:/Users/editn/CLionProjects/kv_module_shared/cmake-build-debug/"

os.add_dll_directory(DLL_FULL_PATH)
os.environ['PATH'] += DLL_FULL_PATH

clib = ctypes.WinDLL(DLL)
print("Using clib={:}".format(clib))

clib.setup.argtypes = ()
clib.setup.restype = ctypes.c_ssize_t
print(clib.setup())


Note: working on window, Python 3.1, Win 11
I tried other variants of ctypes.WinDLL and CDLL with variations on the path description and winmode parameter most of these fail earlier at loading.
Using CLion 2024.1, i build the shared lib, then execute python from CLion. same behavior when executing as flask server form PowerShell(not present in this code since it was specifically stripped to problem at hand)
Additional Info: when replacing with clib = ctypes.CDLL(DLL)
the program still works, but introducing new int; it fails differently (and earlier at load instruction)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libkv_module_shared.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
using malloc() instead of new() works. apparently the problem depends on whether some 3rd tier dependency is found when loading.

Where is the code that fails, and exactly what happens when you run it? Also it looks like you are missing all the correct Python interface packaging in your C code.

Don’t use winmode=1. Also for C size_t use ctypes.c_size_t although it wouldn’t cause the crash. It’s just the correct unsigned type.

FYI, valid winmode values are listed in LoadLibraryEx documentation, but normally you don't need winmode if you provide a valid path and the value 1 is listed as "do not use".

Add details Win and Python version, command lines: how you build your (C) code (or what tools are you using) and how you run it.

I ported my code to linux ubuntu and everything worked. perhaps for posterity someone can explain why this does not work on Windows

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
